# Create a DOCX reading data from Oracle database

Tags: java, automation, docx4j, python-docx

I have a student database (Oracle 11G), I need to create a module(separate) which will generate a student's details in a well-formatted word document. When I give the student ID, I need all the info(Kind of a biodata) of the student in a docx file which is very presentable. I'm not sure how to start, I was exploring Python-docx and java DOCX4j. I need suggestion how can I achieve this. Is there any tool I can do this
Your help is highly appreciated

Comment: Use apache - poi

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the data from Oracle into an XML format, then use content control data binding in your Word document to bind elements in the XML.

All you need to do is inject the XML into the docx as a custom  xml part, and Word will display the results automatically.

docx4j can help you to the inject the XML.  If you don't want to rely on Word to display the results, then you can use docx4j to also apply the bindings.

Or you could try simple variable replacement: https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/VariableReplace.java

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple way to format your Word document directly from Java, you can try [pxDoc](https://www.pxdoc.fr). 
The screenshot below provide an example of code and document generated from an Authors/Books model: whatever the way you request the data from your database, it is easy to render them in a well formatted document.
[simple document generation example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMfFO.png)

[image]

Regarding your use case, you could also generate a document for all students at once. In the context of the screenshot example:

```
for (author:library.authors) {
    var filename = 'c:/MyDocuments/'+author.name+'.docx'
    document fileName:filename {

        /** Content of my document */
    }
```